# using arrow operator to calculate average of 3 members of a structure, need to convert from dot operator to arrow

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

i am practicing c, and i just learned how to assign integers and create structures, i came across the arrow operator and i do not know how to apply it, i researched a little and i now know that a->b is the same as (*a).b and that arrow is used for pointers, my question is how do i convert this code to use arrow operator instead, i tried changing the members from int to int * but it still does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct student {
    char name[10];
    int chem_marks;
    int maths_marks;
    int phy_marks;
};
int main()
{
struct student ahmad;
struct student ali;
struct student abu_abbas;

strcpy (ahmad.name,"ahmad");
ahmad.chem_marks=25;
ahmad.maths_marks=50;
ahmad.phy_marks=90;

strcpy (ali.name,"ali");
ali.chem_marks=29;
ali.maths_marks=90;
ali.phy_marks=13;

strcpy (abu_abbas.name,"abu");
abu_abbas.chem_marks=50;
abu_abbas.maths_marks=12;
abu_abbas.phy_marks=80;

int ahmadavg=(ahmad.chem_marks+ahmad.maths_marks+ahmad.phy_marks)/3;
int aliavg=(ali.chem_marks+ali.maths_marks+ali.phy_marks)/3;
int abu_abbasavg=(abu_abbas.chem_marks+abu_abbas.maths_marks+abu_abbas.phy_marks)/3;


printf("%s  ",ahmad.name);
printf("average:%d\n",ahmadavg);
printf("%s ",ali.name);
printf("average:%d\n",aliavg);
printf("%s ",abu_abbas.name);;
printf("average:%d\n",abu_abbasavg);


}
```

Comment: You're not using pointers in your code, so any attempt to use the the `->` operator is pointless (pun not intended). Read the chapter about pointers in your learning material.

Comment: You should do some research about dynamic memory allocation using `malloc` and `free` as well as how pointers work in general. A simple case would be `struct student *ahmad = malloc(sizeof(*ahmad);` Then everywhere you use `ahmad.whatever` currently you would use `ahmad->whatever` instead and finally when you're done with that variable `free(ahmad)`. You could change your members to pointers but you would need to allocate memory for them and free it when you're done. "It does not work" isn't a useful problem description, and the code you you had trouble with isn't the code in your question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you for the help, i understand my code does not make use of the arrow operator, i wanted to know how would this code look if it used the arrow operator, because i know the concept behind it but i do not know how it is applied. ut you have helped me greatly, thank you.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i know about pointers and therefore i tried to change members to be pointers, i have taken the other comment's advice and tried to implement it in my code but it did no exactly work, my question is, is it not possible to use arrow operator by simply changing the members or structures to pointers using * and not malloc/free which i still do not know what they are, and need to do some research on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the members of the struct being pointers or not, it's about haveing a struct vs. a pointer to a struct.

This small example should make it clear:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

int main()
{
  struct Foo f = {1,2};    // f is a structre

  struct Foo* pf;          // pf is a pointer to a struct Foo
                           // it points nowhere

  pf = &f;                 // now pf points to f

  printf("%d %d\n", f.a, f.b);         // direct access to f

  printf("%d %d\n", pf->a, pf->b);     // access via a pointer
  printf("%d %d\n", (*pf).a, (*pf).b); // access via a pointer (same as line above)
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the help